Ensure Horizontal Dashed Lines Always Meet Circle Boundaries Without Gaps or Crossing in Responsive Layout
I have a layout where horizontal dashed lines must intersect exactly with the boundaries of circles and not cross them, regardless of the screen size or layout changes.
For the left line: It should start at the left boundary of the left circle and extend off-screen to the left.
For the right line: It should start at the right boundary of the right circle and extend off-screen to the right.
The dashed lines must not cross the circle boundary, and they should end precisely at the circle boundary.

However, on large screens or after resizing the window, I sometimes notice a gap between the dashed line and the circle boundary or instances where the dashed line crosses into the circle.
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import gsap from 'gsap';
import Heading from '../Heading/Heading';

const IconSectionDesktop = ({ circularSection }) => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const observerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const container = containerRef.current;
    const serviceElements = container.querySelectorAll('.service-item');
    const circles = container.querySelectorAll('.animated-circle');
    const lines = container.querySelectorAll('.animated-line');

    // Staggered slide-in animation
    const slideTimeline = gsap.timeline({ paused: true });
    slideTimeline
      .fromTo(serviceElements[0], 
        { x: -200, opacity: 0 }, 
        { x: 0, opacity: 1, duration: 0.7 }
      )
      .fromTo(serviceElements[1], 
        { y: -200, opacity: 0 }, 
        { y: 0, opacity: 1, duration: 0.7 }, 
        0.3
      )
      .fromTo(serviceElements[2], 
        { x: 200, opacity: 0 }, 
        { x: 0, opacity: 1, duration: 0.7 }, 
        0.6
      );

    // Dashed animation function
    const animateDashedElements = () => {
      // Animate circles
      circles.forEach(circle => {
        gsap.set(circle, { strokeDasharray: "10 10" });
        gsap.to(circle, {
          strokeDashoffset: -1000,
          duration: 17,
          repeat: -1,
          ease: "linear",
        });
      });

      // Animate straight lines
      lines.forEach(line => {
        gsap.set(line, { strokeDasharray: "10 10" });
        gsap.to(line, {
          strokeDashoffset: -1000,
          duration: 17,
          repeat: -1,
          ease: "linear",
        });
      });
    };

    // Intersection Observer
    observerRef.current = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            // Play staggered slide-in animation
            slideTimeline.play();
            
            // Start dashed animations after slide-in
            setTimeout(animateDashedElements, 1000);
            
            // Disconnect observer after triggering
            observerRef.current.disconnect();
          }
        });
      },
      { threshold: 0.7 }
    );

    // Observe the container
    if (container) {
      observerRef.current.observe(container);
    }

    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      if (observerRef.current) {
        observerRef.current.disconnect();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  const renderDashedLine = (position, direction) => {
    const lineClasses = `absolute top-1/3 ${
      direction === 'left' ? 'left-full' : 'right-full'
    } w-screen transform -translate-y-1/2`;

    return (
      <div className={lineClasses}>
        <svg width="100%" height="2" className="overflow-visible">
          <line
            x1="0"
            y1="1"
            x2="100%"
            y2="1"
            className="animated-line"
            stroke="#64FF37"
            strokeWidth="2"
            strokeDasharray="10 10"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen text-white px-60 overflow-hidden">
      <div className="relative flex justify-between w-full">
        {circularSection.map((service, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={`relative flex flex-col items-center text-center service-item ${
              index === Math.floor(circularSection.length / 2) ? 'mt-28' : ''
            }`}
          >
            {/* Vertical Dashed Line for Center Circle */}
            {index === Math.floor(circularSection.length / 2) && (
              <div className="absolute bottom-full left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 h-screen overflow-hidden">
                <svg width="2" height="100%" className="overflow-hidden">
                  <line
                    x1="1"
                    y1="0"
                    x2="1"
                    y2="100%"
                    className="animated-line"
                    stroke="#64FF37"
                    strokeWidth="2"
                    strokeDasharray="10 10"
                  />
                </svg>
              </div>
            )}

            {/* Horizontal Dashed Lines */}
            {index !== 0 && index !== Math.floor(circularSection.length / 2) && (
              renderDashedLine(index, 'left')
            )}
            {index !== circularSection.length - 1 && index !== Math.floor(circularSection.length / 2) && (
              renderDashedLine(index, 'right')
            )}

            {/* Circle with Icon */}
            <div className="relative flex items-center justify-center w-60 h-60">
              <svg
                className="absolute inset-0 w-full h-full"
                viewBox="0 0 240 240"
              >
                <circle
                  cx="120"
                  cy="120"
                  r="119"
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="#64FF37"
                  strokeWidth="2"
                  className="animated-circle"
                  strokeDasharray="10 10"
                />
              </svg>
              <img
                src={service.icon}
                alt={`${service.word} Icon`}
                className="w-2/5 z-10"
              />
            </div>

            {/* Title */}
            <Heading text={service.word} size="text-40px" className="mt-6" />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default IconSectionDesktop;


Issue:
Despite dynamically calculating the positions and dimensions of the circles:
I sometimes observe a gap between the dashed line and the circle boundary.
In some cases, the dashed line crosses into the circle instead of ending exactly at the boundary.
This issue is more noticeable on large screens or after resizing the window.

